# Tetris Javascript - Draw Grid onto Canvas

Tags: javascript

I tried adding this line to my `draw()` function. but it just creates a stroke border. I'm looking to create a grid overlay onto the game board.

```
context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
context.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Appreciate any help or suggestions :

```js
// Variable for Board
const canvas = document.getElementById('tetris');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// 12(width) by 20(height) squares
const arena = createMatrix(12, 20);

context.scale(20, 20);

// Clear Board on Lose
function clearBoard() {
    let rowCount = 1;
    outer: for (let y = arena.length - 1; y > 0; --y) {
        for (let x = 0; x < arena[y].length; ++x) {
            if (arena[y][x] === 0) {
                continue outer;
            }
        }
        const row = arena.splice(y, 1)[0].fill(0); //takes complete row out
        arena.unshift(row);
        ++y;

        player.score += rowCount * 10;
        rowCount *= 2;
    }
}

// Create Boundaries to prevent out of canvas movement
function boundary(arena, player) {
    const [m, o] = [player.matrix, player.pos];
    for (let y = 0; y < m.length; ++y) {
        for (let x = 0; x < m[y].length; ++x) {
            if (m[y][x] !== 0 &&
                (arena[y + o.y] &&
                    arena[y + o.y][x + o.x]) !== 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function createMatrix(w, h) {
    const matrix = [];
    while (h--) {
        matrix.push(new Array(w).fill(0));
    }
    return matrix;
}

function createPiece(type) {
    if (type === 'T') {
        return [
            [0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [0, 1, 0],
        ];
    } else if (type === 'O') {
        return [
            [2, 2],
            [2, 2],
        ];
    } else if (type === 'L') {
        return [
            [0, 3, 0],
            [0, 3, 0],
            [0, 3, 3],
        ];
    } else if (type === 'J') {
        return [
            [0, 4, 0],
            [0, 4, 0],
            [4, 4, 0],
        ];
    } else if (type === 'I') {
        return [
            [0, 5, 0, 0],
            [0, 5, 0, 0],
            [0, 5, 0, 0],
            [0, 5, 0, 0],
        ];
    } else if (type === 'S') {
        return [
            [0, 6, 6],
            [6, 6, 0],
            [0, 0, 0],
        ];
    } else if (type === 'Z') {
        return [
            [7, 7, 0],
            [0, 7, 7],
            [0, 0, 0],
        ];
    }
}

function draw() {
    context.fillStyle = '#000';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    drawMatrix(arena, { x: 0, y: 0 });
    drawMatrix(player.matrix, player.pos);
}

function drawMatrix(matrix, offset) {
    matrix.forEach((row, y) => {
        row.forEach((value, x) => {
            if (value !== 0) {
                context.fillStyle = colors[value];
                context.fillRect(x + offset.x, y + offset.y, 1, 1);
            }
        });
    });
}

// Merge to boundard and piece when it touches bottom
function merge(arena, player) {
    player.matrix.forEach((row, y) => {
        row.forEach((value, x) => {
            if (value !== 0) {
                arena[y + player.pos.y][x + player.pos.x] = value;
            }
        });
    });
}

// Movement for Down
function playerDrop() {
    player.pos.y++;
    if (boundary(arena, player)) {
        player.pos.y--;
        merge(arena, player);
        playerReset();
        clearBoard();
        updateScore();
    }
    dropCounter = 0;
}

// Movement for Left/Right
function playerMove(offset) {
    player.pos.x += offset;
    if (boundary(arena, player)) {
        player.pos.x -= offset;
    }
}

// Movement for Rotation - Clockwise and Anti-Clockwise
function playerRotate(dir) {
    const pos = player.pos.x;
    // initialise offset variable
    let offset = 1;
    rotate(player.matrix, dir);
    // Check collision
    while (boundary(arena, player)) {
        player.pos.x += offset;
        offset = -(offset + (offset > 0 ? 1 : -1));
        if (offset > player.matrix[0].length) {
            rotate(player.matrix, -dir);
            player.pos.x = pos;
            return;
        }
    }
}

// Addon to confine to boundary
function rotate(matrix, dir) {
    for (let y = 0; y < matrix.length; ++y) {
        for (let x = 0; x < y; ++x) {
            [
                matrix[x][y],
                matrix[y][x],
            ] = [
                matrix[y][x],
                matrix[x][y],
            ];
        }
    }
    if (dir > 0) {
        matrix.forEach(row => row.reverse());
    } else {
        matrix.reverse();
    }
}

// Produce Random Piece / Reset Player Score on Lose
function playerReset() {
    const pieces = 'ILJOTSZ';
    player.matrix = createPiece(pieces[pieces.length * Math.random() | 0]);
    player.pos.y = 0;
    player.pos.x = (arena[0].length / 2 | 0) - (player.matrix[0].length / 2 | 0);
    if (boundary(arena, player)) {
        arena.forEach(row => row.fill(0));
        player.score = 0;
        updateScore();
    }
}

// Timer Count
let dropCounter = 0; // prevent animation from dropping past canvas
let dropInterval = 1000; // 1sec drop speed

// Incremental Time
let lastTime = 0;

function update(time = 0) {
    const deltaTime = time - lastTime;
    lastTime = time;

    dropCounter += deltaTime;
    if (dropCounter > dropInterval) {
        playerDrop();
    }
    draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

// Movement Controls
document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    if (event.keyCode === 37) { // KeyLeft : Move Left
        playerMove(-1);
    } else if (event.keyCode === 39) { // KeyRight : Move Right
        playerMove(1);
    } else if (event.keyCode === 40) { // KeyDown : Move Down 1 Step
        playerDrop();
    } else if (event.keyCode === 40 * 2) {

    } else if (event.keyCode === 81) { // Q : Rotate Anti-Clockwise
        playerRotate(-1);
    } else if (event.keyCode === 69) { // E : Rotate Clockwise
        playerRotate(1);
    }
});

// Track Score
function updateScore() {
    document.getElementById('score').innerText = player.score;
}

// Random Color for Bricks via Index
const colors = [
    null,
    '#FF0D72',
    '#0DC2FF',
    '#0DFF72',
    '#F538FF',
    '#FF8E0D',
    '#FFE138',
    '#3877FF',
];

// Game Init Settings
const player = {
    pos: { x: 0, y: 0 },
    matrix: null,
    score: 0,
}

playerReset();
updateScore();
update();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <Title>Tetris</Title>
    <style>
        body {
            background: #202028;
            color: #fff;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 2em;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        canvas {
            border: solid .2em #fff;
            height: 80vh;
        }
        
        div#display {
            font-size: .5em !important;
        }
        
        #instruction {
            font-size: .3em !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="display">
        Score:
        <div id="score"></div>
    </div>
    <canvas id="tetris" width="240" height="400"></canvas>
    <script src="tetris.js"></script>
    <div id="instruction">
        <p>Movement Controls:</p>
        <p>KeyDown , KeyLeft, KeyRight</p>
        <p>Q : Rotate Counter-Clockwise, E : Rotate Clockwise</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It seems that your canvas is only a few pixels wide, so you won't be able to make a finegrained grid layout, as a linestroke will will up one complete row/column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your canvas is so small that you won't be able to draw a grid, you can still create a grid made out of cells using the following function:

```js
function drawGrid(arena) {
  arena.forEach((row, y) => {
    row.forEach((value, x) => {
      const isEvenX = x % 2 != 0;
      const isEvenY = y % 2 != 0;
      const color = isEvenX ?
        isEvenY ? "#292929" : "#212121" :
        isEvenY ? "#212121" : "#292929";
      context.fillStyle = color;
      context.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    });
  });
}
```

```js
// Variable for Board
const canvas = document.getElementById('tetris');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// 12(width) by 20(height) squares
const arena = createMatrix(12, 20);

context.scale(20, 20);

// Clear Board on Lose
function clearBoard() {
  let rowCount = 1;
  outer: for (let y = arena.length - 1; y > 0; --y) {
    for (let x = 0; x < arena[y].length; ++x) {
      if (arena[y][x] === 0) {
        continue outer;
      }
    }
    const row = arena.splice(y, 1)[0].fill(0); //takes complete row out
    arena.unshift(row);
    ++y;

    player.score += rowCount * 10;
    rowCount *= 2;
  }
}

// Create Boundaries to prevent out of canvas movement
function boundary(arena, player) {
  const [m, o] = [player.matrix, player.pos];
  for (let y = 0; y < m.length; ++y) {
    for (let x = 0; x < m[y].length; ++x) {
      if (m[y][x] !== 0 &&
        (arena[y + o.y] &&
          arena[y + o.y][x + o.x]) !== 0) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function createMatrix(w, h) {
  const matrix = [];
  while (h--) {
    matrix.push(new Array(w).fill(0));
  }
  return matrix;
}

function createPiece(type) {
  if (type === 'T') {
    return [
      [0, 0, 0],
      [1, 1, 1],
      [0, 1, 0],
    ];
  } else if (type === 'O') {
    return [
      [2, 2],
      [2, 2],
    ];
  } else if (type === 'L') {
    return [
      [0, 3, 0],
      [0, 3, 0],
      [0, 3, 3],
    ];
  } else if (type === 'J') {
    return [
      [0, 4, 0],
      [0, 4, 0],
      [4, 4, 0],
    ];
  } else if (type === 'I') {
    return [
      [0, 5, 0, 0],
      [0, 5, 0, 0],
      [0, 5, 0, 0],
      [0, 5, 0, 0],
    ];
  } else if (type === 'S') {
    return [
      [0, 6, 6],
      [6, 6, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
    ];
  } else if (type === 'Z') {
    return [
      [7, 7, 0],
      [0, 7, 7],
      [0, 0, 0],
    ];
  }
}

function draw() {
  context.fillStyle = '#000';
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawGrid(arena);
  drawMatrix(arena, {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  });
  drawMatrix(player.matrix, player.pos);
}

function drawGrid(arena) {
  arena.forEach((row, y) => {
    row.forEach((value, x) => {
      const isEvenX = x % 2 != 0;
      const isEvenY = y % 2 != 0;
      const color = isEvenX ?
        isEvenY ? "#292929" : "#212121" :
        isEvenY ? "#212121" : "#292929";
      context.fillStyle = color;
      context.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    });
  });
}

function drawMatrix(matrix, offset) {
  matrix.forEach((row, y) => {
    row.forEach((value, x) => {
      if (value !== 0) {
        context.fillStyle = colors[value];
        context.fillRect(x + offset.x, y + offset.y, 1, 1);
      }
    });
  });
}

// Merge to boundard and piece when it touches bottom
function merge(arena, player) {
  player.matrix.forEach((row, y) => {
    row.forEach((value, x) => {
      if (value !== 0) {
        arena[y + player.pos.y][x + player.pos.x] = value;
      }
    });
  });
}

// Movement for Down
function playerDrop() {
  player.pos.y++;
  if (boundary(arena, player)) {
    player.pos.y--;
    merge(arena, player);
    playerReset();
    clearBoard();
    updateScore();
  }
  dropCounter = 0;
}

// Movement for Left/Right
function playerMove(offset) {
  player.pos.x += offset;
  if (boundary(arena, player)) {
    player.pos.x -= offset;
  }
}

// Movement for Rotation - Clockwise and Anti-Clockwise
function playerRotate(dir) {
  const pos = player.pos.x;
  // initialise offset variable
  let offset = 1;
  rotate(player.matrix, dir);
  // Check collision
  while (boundary(arena, player)) {
    player.pos.x += offset;
    offset = -(offset + (offset > 0 ? 1 : -1));
    if (offset > player.matrix[0].length) {
      rotate(player.matrix, -dir);
      player.pos.x = pos;
      return;
    }
  }
}

// Addon to confine to boundary
function rotate(matrix, dir) {
  for (let y = 0; y < matrix.length; ++y) {
    for (let x = 0; x < y; ++x) {
      [
        matrix[x][y],
        matrix[y][x],
      ] = [
        matrix[y][x],
        matrix[x][y],
      ];
    }
  }
  if (dir > 0) {
    matrix.forEach(row => row.reverse());
  } else {
    matrix.reverse();
  }
}

// Produce Random Piece / Reset Player Score on Lose
function playerReset() {
  const pieces = 'ILJOTSZ';
  player.matrix = createPiece(pieces[pieces.length * Math.random() | 0]);
  player.pos.y = 0;
  player.pos.x = (arena[0].length / 2 | 0) - (player.matrix[0].length / 2 | 0);
  if (boundary(arena, player)) {
    arena.forEach(row => row.fill(0));
    player.score = 0;
    updateScore();
  }
}

// Timer Count
let dropCounter = 0; // prevent animation from dropping past canvas
let dropInterval = 1000; // 1sec drop speed

// Incremental Time
let lastTime = 0;

function update(time = 0) {
  const deltaTime = time - lastTime;
  lastTime = time;

  dropCounter += deltaTime;
  if (dropCounter > dropInterval) {
    playerDrop();
  }
  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

// Movement Controls
document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  if (event.keyCode === 37) { // KeyLeft : Move Left
    playerMove(-1);
  } else if (event.keyCode === 39) { // KeyRight : Move Right
    playerMove(1);
  } else if (event.keyCode === 40) { // KeyDown : Move Down 1 Step
    playerDrop();
  } else if (event.keyCode === 40 * 2) {

  } else if (event.keyCode === 81) { // Q : Rotate Anti-Clockwise
    playerRotate(-1);
  } else if (event.keyCode === 69) { // E : Rotate Clockwise
    playerRotate(1);
  }
});

// Track Score
function updateScore() {
  document.getElementById('score').innerText = player.score;
}

// Random Color for Bricks via Index
const colors = [
  null,
  '#FF0D72',
  '#0DC2FF',
  '#0DFF72',
  '#F538FF',
  '#FF8E0D',
  '#FFE138',
  '#3877FF',
];

// Game Init Settings
const player = {
  pos: {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  matrix: null,
  score: 0,
}

playerReset();
updateScore();
update();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <Title>Tetris</Title>
  <style>
    body {
      background: #202028;
      color: #fff;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 2em;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    canvas {
      border: solid .2em #fff;
      height: 80vh;
    }
    
    div#display {
      font-size: .5em !important;
    }
    
    #instruction {
      font-size: .3em !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="display">
    Score:
    <div id="score"></div>
  </div>
  <canvas id="tetris" width="240" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="tetris.js"></script>
  <div id="instruction">
    <p>Movement Controls:</p>
    <p>KeyDown , KeyLeft, KeyRight</p>
    <p>Q : Rotate Counter-Clockwise, E : Rotate Clockwise</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: would it be easier if I just overlay a scalable SVG onto HTML to show the grid using z-index?

Comment: I don't think it's easier, as you will have to put a lot of effort in making it fit completely. The nice thing about a good tetris implementation is that you can make the size of the arena completely customizable with a custom length and width, using this approach that is not possible.

Comment: It would be easier to render you tetris arena using a correct scale that allows the addition of more details (like the grid).